# PHP Create Function Convert for 7.2

Tags: php, php-7.2

I tried existing questions in the forum and I was not able to figure out how I can convert this below code using `create_function`. When I run the application I get a deprecated error in the logs. Can you please post the converted code?

```
private function _set_error_handler() {
    set_error_handler(
        create_function(
            '$severity, $message, $file, $line',
            'throw new Exception($message . " in file " . $file . " on line " . $line);'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: See [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: I am not able to come up with a replacement code. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

[`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler) requires a [Callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

You can use [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) :

```
private function _set_error_handler() {
    set_error_handler(
        function($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
            throw new Exception($message . " in file " . $file . " on line " . $line);
        }
    );
}
```

See [live demo](https://3v4l.org/uQV0J)

Or a separated function :

```
private function _set_error_handler() {
    set_error_handler([$this, 'on_error']);
}

// should be public
public function on_error($severity, $message, $file, $line) {
    throw new Exception($message . " in file " . $file . " on line " . $line);
}
```

See [live demo](https://3v4l.org/3vulM)